# How to run python script until it ends without errors?

Tags: python

I have a following question. I have a script my_script.py. I would like to run it again, until it ends without errors. I run my_script.py from master.py like this:

```py
import my_script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_script.main()
```

I tried:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  while True:
    try:
        my_script.main()
    except:
        pass
```

but this never ends. How can I end master.py when my_script.py ends succesfully ?

Comment: Put a `break` after the method call inside the `try`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set a flag or break to see if you finished or not, e.g.:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  while True:
    try:
        my_script.main()
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks. And finished should be defined before the while loop as True?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, had a typo. You can either use the flag or just break, both would work.